# Multer With Meteor uploading files to .meteor folder

Tags: javascript, meteor, multer

I'm using multer in meteor to upload files. But instead of uploading files to public **uploads** folder, it's uploading file to .meteor build folder. Any suggestions why it's happening??

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({


 destination: function (req, file, cb) { 
    if (!existsSync('../uploads')){
      mkdirSync('../uploads');
    }
    cb(null, path.resolve('../uploads'))
  },
  filename: (req, file, ab) => {
    ab(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000)}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this in development or production?

Comment: Isn't the better question how you will find this upload folder in production? Production folder layout is very different from development. I would store the files in an absolute path instead and serve them statically, or, if they are not too big, just store them as base64 a collection.